# Sketching the graph without software

Tags: graphing-functions

How to sketch the graph $|y|=\frac{|sin(x)|}{sin(x)}$?

I tried myself and have got this result:
[image]

Is this correct? I can't check it on Desmos, it says that graph has unresolved detail.

Comment: Wait I misread this. Is that meant to be ${|y|}$? Or is it meant to be just ${y}$?

Comment: Are you sure about $|y|$ ? If yes, there cannot be negative values.

Comment: Yes it's $|y|$.

Comment: Your sketch is Ok for function $y = f(x) = \frac{\mid \sin x \mid}{\sin x}$...

Comment: @YvesDaoust So only upper line segments will stay? Or?

Comment: ${|y|=-1}$ for example doesn't make sense, since ${|y|\geq 0\ \forall\ y \in \mathbb{R}}$

Comment: @Yourong'DZR'Zang: not for all $x$.

Comment: @Yourong'DZR'Zang In the question, OP is plotting ${|y|=\frac{|\sin(x)|}{\sin(x)}}$. When ${\sin(x)}$ is negative, ${|y|=}$ some negative number does not have any solution

Comment: @Yourong'DZR'Zang: no, the function is only defined for half of the reals...

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes sorry that was my mistake

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose sorry I was wrong.

Comment: @Yourong'DZR'Zang No problem :)

Answer (score 0):

As $|y|\ge0$, the equation has the two solutions $y=\pm1$ for $x\in(2k\pi,\pi+2k\pi)$.

Comment: How does it change my graph?

Comment: @NikaChelidze: think about it.

Comment: I replied above. So only upper line segments will stay? Or would it be y=1 line?

Comment: @NikaChelidze: post your new plot and I'll tell you.